# Example of non unital homomorphism of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

What's an example of nonzero non unital homomorphism between unital associative algebras?If there any example in case of Banach algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\phi:\mathbb{C}\to M_2(\mathbb{C})$ given by $\phi(z)=\begin{pmatrix}z&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. This is a $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras, but it is of course non-unital since $\phi(1)\neq I_{M_2}$.