# $C^\ast$ -algebra : Can we assume image of identity is identity?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

In Conway's A Course in Operator Theory, proposition 1.7 (e) is

> If $\rho:A \to B$ is $\ast$-homomorphism, then $\|\rho(a)\| \leq \|a\|$ for all $a$ in $A$.

and the beginning of the proof is

> First note that by adjoining an identity if necessary, it can be assumed that $A$ is unital. Now, the definition of a $\ast$-homomorphism does not assume that  $\rho(1)$ is the identity of $B$. How ever it is easy to see that $\rho(1)$ is an identity for $\rho(A)$. So there is no loss of generality in assuming that $B$ has an identity and $\rho(1) = 1$.

I could understand "$\rho(1)$ is identity for $\rho(A)$", but I'm stack at "there is no loss of generality in assuming that $B$ has an identity and $\rho(1) = 1$".

Please some advice to understand this.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess the only missing piece is this: if $\rho$ is not surjective, we can always consider $\rho$ as $\rho:A\to\rho(A)$. Thereby, both the domain and the image of $\rho$ can be considered as $C^*$-algebras, where $rho(1)=1$.

Comment: I see...Does it mean that (that may be an inaccurate representation) $\mathbb{C} \subset \rho(A) \subset B$ since $\rho(A)$ is unital $C^\ast$-algebra ?

Answer (score 1):

A $*$-homomorphism $f: A \to B$ is such that $f(a)^* = f(a^*)$.

Hence, we have $\rho(1)^* = \rho(1^*) = \rho(1)$ since $1^* = 1$. Moreover, $\rho(1)$ behaves similarly to $1_B := 1 \in B$.   Thus if $\rho(1)$ has this key defining property similar to $1_B$ then there is no fault in assuming WLOG $\rho(1) = 1_B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! However, I still have a question about this. If $A$ is unital from the first, and $\rho(1_A) \neq 1_B$,  how should we do "$\rho(1_A) = 1_B$"?

Comment: Are you asking what to do in the case where $A$ is unital, that is has a unit, but the homomorphism isn't unital? Namely, it doesn't map the unit to the unit? For example, the answer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131756/example-of-non-unital-homomorphism-of-algebras

Comment: Yes, my question is about the case like the post.

Comment: You can certainly have that $\rho(1_A) \not = 1_b$ but since both elements are self-adjoint it doesn't cause issue with assuming they are equal for the purposes of the proof.

Comment: Cf. Cor. 1.3.7 https://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf It gives a proof without making this assumption. So it isn't necessary to make this assumption; however, there is no harm in making such an assumption. **EDIT**: Just noticed, this assumes the mapping is unital but they talk about handling self-adjoint elements so I don't think it is necessary they assume the mapping is unital. However, I am not very knowledgable in this area so perhaps I am missing something.